# "Do you got anything?" vs. "Do you have anything?"

Tags: difference, american-english

Is there a nuance of difference when someone asks *do you got anything for me?* as opposed to *do you have anything for me?* I am aware that the former isn't really grammatically correct, but that's what Rachel said in the 12th episod of the 7th season of *Friends*. The context is Rachel told Tag to go to look for the folder that he was supposed to overnight, but didn't because Rachel forgot to put it on Tag's desk. And to avoid emberrassment Rachel is making out that she actually did. Here it is:

> Hi! I got you some coffee. To, uh… (She looks for a place to set it on his messy desk and he clears a spot for her to set it down.) …fair enough. So! **Do you got anything for me**?

Here is [scene](https://youtu.be/cuYhswl2sII). It is at around 3 minutes and 31 seconds.

Comment: It's just informal; "have you got anything for me" or "do you have anything for me" would not change the meaning or tone.

Comment: Are you sure that the actor playing Rachel says "*Do you got anything...?*" and not "*You got anything...?*" Can you post a link?

Comment: actually a little like mixing a slangy, grammatically incorrect expression up with grammatically correct English. quote from this post: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-got-californian.2655092/

Comment: My hearing is not great but I would say that Rachel is saying "**So**, you got anything for me?" but that initial sound is said so quickly, I might well be mistaken.

Comment: You might want to try to wath it at 0.5 speed. There is alost the transcrit of it.

Comment: Transcripts are often good on YouTube but they're not always without mistakes. I'll try listening at a slower speed. EDIT: It says "So you're gonna sing for me?" :)) I definitely hear the "so" by the way.

Comment: "Hi.  I got you some coffee.  So, did you get anything for me?"  The "did you" is pronounced *juh* or /dʒə/

Comment: I got the transcript from here https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0712.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do you got anything for me?**

is simply a *very* informal way of asking:

**Do you have anything for me?**.

It's not grammatically correct and not really all that common. You should only encounter it in spoken English (or written dialog).

Answer (score 1):

This gets taught in different ways in different countries, you can say "have you got something" or "do you have something" and these are the same. "Do you got something" sounds in this case like Rachel is confused and tired.

The other thing is that she's used "got" in the past tense, as "I got you coffee", so she might have meant "did you get anything for me", but as above, tired and confused and saying things wrong as a result.